# Where do i find microbes like tardigrades in winter

Tags: microbiology, microscopy

Just bought a microscope and i want to see microbes like tardigrades.  Where should i look? I have found many bacteria and what seems to be motionless single celled organism.  I want to see movement and feeding.  Ps snow on the ground and frozen ground

Answer (score 3):

Tardigrades are best found by soaking moss in water. Even in the winter, under the snow, that is the best place to look. Let tap water sit overnight, uncovered before you add it to the moss to let the chlorine come out. And then strain the water with fine-mesh cloth to see what was in the moss. I would not call tardigrades "microbes" though. Even though "microbes" is not a scientific term, I think of microbes as bacteria, while tardigrades are microscopic animals.